# Can I install only 1 of Origin games to another drive?

Tags: origin

I'm getting a bit tired or waiting for ages for my PC to start up, so I'm planning on purchasing an SSD to boot my windows with it. Then I thought that it might be nice to have BF3 installed on it too. Unfortunately I can't find any info on how to install *only one* of Origin games to a different location.

So the question is:

Is it possible to install only BF3(for example) on an SSD and all other games to the normal HDD? And if not, will there be a *big* difference in starting time of BF3 if I start it from an SSD or a HDD?

Thanks,

Any information would be appreciated

Comment: Oh the problems of not being able to use Steam for some games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this at the moment, is to create a symlink and then move all files of the game to this new location. This requires to have NTFS as filesystem. This reroutes a directory or file to the true location of the file/directory.

More informations:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

For your second question:

I personally would not install BF3 on a SSD since it does not require streaming textures and therefore, a SSD only provides a very minimal advantage when loading the level initially.

Comment: Another option: Convince enough gamers to refuse using Origin and giving EA money until EA agrees to change their policies.  This is how the world works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer on this question will allow you to move any single origin game to a different location.

[Is it possible to install games to different hard drives?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127822/is-it-possible-to-install-games-to-different-hard-drives/127835#127835)