# Is it possible to install games to different hard drives?

Tags: origin

I normally use Steam, but after purchasing the latest Humble Bundle I acquired several Origin games. My main hard drive is a 128GB SSD, but it's is almost full. I like to keep a few games I'm playing on there, and the rest installed on my 1TB secondary drive. In Steam it is simple and easy to select a game and chose which hard drive to install it to. Is there a way to do this on Origin?

The only thing I've found so far is this:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Seems a little OTT for what should be a simple procedure.

Comment: A junction point is actually pretty simple, I use Link Shell Extension http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html not sure if there's a naitive way to do this in origin though, so comment instead of answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Go to Origin advanced settings and setup the folder for your games.
2. Download and install the games you want to install under that folder.
3. Repeat the process for all hard drives you want to use.

It will not move the game you already installed on another drive. It will simply notify you that the games already installed will not be moved and you can continue.

[image: Origin > Application Settings > Advanced > Downloaded Games > Your games will be installed to the following location]

Answer (score 4):

[Steam Mover](http://www.traynier.com/software/steammover) (as its name suggests) was written to move Steam games. However, it works by simply copying all files from one location to another, then creating a junction point where the old files used to be. This means that all you need to do is locate the bulk of the game files you would like to move, and use Steam Mover to move them. This would work for Steam, Origin, installs from CDs, anything.

As a side note, it can be used to move applications, document folders, etc. It's best set up for moving folders between two parent folders, tho, much as you would if you had a games folder on your SSD, and one on your HDD.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it for Mass Effect 3 and Need For Speed Most Wanted from D to J:. You can modify the commands to suit your needs.

#### Step 1:

Move the game folders of the desired games you would like to migrate to another hard drive or volume.
[image: recursively moved two games from D:\OriginGames (SSD) to J:\OriginGames hdd]

#### Step 2:

After the folders and files themselves have been moved into the desired volume, open a console with Winkey+R - type *cmd* press enter and use *mklink* in the newely opened cmd console window to make a so called symbolik link between the old and new folder locations, like this:

```
mklink /d "D:\OriginGames\Mass Effect 3" "J:\OriginGames\Mass Effect 3"
```

Don't forget double quotes if you have spaces in the folder names and the /d switch.

This basically tells the Windows OS to use a symlink, and thus this "trick" works application-wide.
[image: Step 2 - make directory simlinks using mklink]

#### You are done.

After this in the Origin UI the "Play" button becomes again available for the desired games, eventhough, they now reside on another HDD/SSD volume.